# Argument names of Arithmetic Operators

Tags: r

When looking at arithmetic operators they show that their arguments have the names `e1` and `e2`. When using those names it looks like that they are ignored and only the position is used.

```
`/`(e1 = 1, e2 = 2)
#[1] 0.5

`/`(e2 = 1, e1 = 2) #Here I would have expected 2 as the result
#[1] 0.5
```

Is it only possible to define who is the dividend and who is the divisor by the position or are there possibilities to use argument names?

When creating a Custom Binary Operator the names are not ignored.

```
`%div%` <- function(e1, e2) {e1 / e2}

`%div%`(e1 = 1, e2 = 2)
#[1] 0.5

`%div%`(e2 = 1, e1 = 2)
#[1] 2
```

Comment: Maybe related: `?groupGeneric`

Comment: From the above `?groupGeneric`, there is this statement under **Group "Ops"**: *If the members of this group are called as functions, any argument names are removed to ensure that positional matching is always used.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `?groupGeneric`:

> If the members of this group are called as functions, any argument names are removed to ensure that positional matching is always used.

Note/tip: I got to that help page via `?Arithmetic`, then in *Details* section mentions to see *Ops* for dispatch:

> The unary and binary arithmetic operators are generic functions:
> methods can be written for them individually or via the Ops group
> generic function. (See Ops for how dispatch is computed.)

Answer (score 5):

When we dive into the [`C` source code of `/`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ae727eb50b37983784e1ea929760b40f6234e137/src/main/arithmetic.c), we can see the piece of code below for two scalars (I am not a R expert for analyzing the source code but probably we can find some clue there as well).

It seems the argument names are not taken into account, but only the positions.

[image]